# cannot for the life of me resolve GetSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled may produce NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I know this has been discussed a lot but I've tried everything, changing getSupportActionBar to getActionBar, changing my layout to fragment activity, action bar activity, changing my layout to toolbar.  Nothing seems to remove that warning.  Thanks for your help.

Oh and if there's confusion over main_menu.xml vs menu_main.xml, it's because I had an overflow menu and I'm trying to switch it over to a sliding drawer menu.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package me.paxana.alerta;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toolbar;


import com.parse.ParseUser;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import me.paxana.alerta.adapter.SlidingMenuAdapter;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment1;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment2;
import me.paxana.alerta.fragment.Fragment3;
import me.paxana.alerta.model.ItemSlideMenu;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private List<ItemSlideMenu> listSliding;
    private SlidingMenuAdapter adapter;
    private ListView listViewSliding;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
             if (currentUser == null) {
                navigateToLogin();
            }

        else {
                Log.i(TAG, currentUser.getUsername());
            }

        listViewSliding = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_sliding_menu);
        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        listSliding = new ArrayList<>();
        //add item for sliding list
        listSliding. add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_settings, "Settings"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.drawable.ic_action_about, "About"));
        listSliding.add(new ItemSlideMenu(R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Android"));
        adapter = new SlidingMenuAdapter(this, listSliding);
        listViewSliding.setAdapter(adapter);


        //display icon to open/close slider
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        if (mToolbar != null)
        {
            setActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0); // or other
        }

        //set title
        setTitle(listSliding.get(0).getTitle());
        //item selected
        listViewSliding.setItemChecked(0, true);
        //close menu
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
        //handle on item click
        listViewSliding.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                //set title
                setTitle(listSliding.get(position).getTitle());
                //item selected
                listViewSliding.setItemChecked(position, true);
                //close menu
                drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listViewSliding);
            }

        });

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };

        drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

    }

    private void navigateToLogin() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }

        int itemId = item.getItemId();
        if (itemId == R.id.action_logout) {
            ParseUser.logOut();
            navigateToLogin();

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }
//create method replace fragment
    private void replaceFragment(int pos) {
        android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (pos) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                    break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Fragment2();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new Fragment3();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new Fragment1();
                break;
        }
        if(null != fragment) {
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_content, fragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    }
}
```

**Activity_Main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.app.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    tools:context="me.paxana.alerta.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/main_content">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv_sliding_menu"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />
</android.support.v4.app.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().foo;
```

Change `setActionBar()` to `setSupportActionBar()`.  Until you call the 'set' method for the appcompat library's wrapper the corresponding `get` method will return null.